# Intercepting link clicks with QWebEngineView in PyQt6

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt6

I am trying to intercept links clicked within a QWebEngineView widget in PyQt6. For now, I would like the only behavior of clicking a link to be to print "hello" and do nothing else. The following code works and does not need a QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEnginePage

import sys

class ReadField(QWebEngineView) :
        def __init__(self, page):
                super().__init__(page, None)

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
        def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, type, isMainFrame: bool) -> bool:
                print("hello")
                if type == QWebEnginePage.NavigationType.NavigationTypeLinkClicked: return False
                return super().acceptNavigationRequest(url, type, isMainFrame)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
page = Page()
rf = ReadField(page)
rf.setHtml("<a href=\"http://test\">test</a>")
rf.show()
app.exec()
app.quit()
```

I would like to move the creation of the Page element within the constructor of ReadField. This would give the following code.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEnginePage

import sys

class ReadField(QWebEngineView) :
        def __init__(self):
                page = Page()
                super().__init__(page, None)

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
        def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, type, isMainFrame: bool) -> bool:
                print("hello")
                if type == QWebEnginePage.NavigationType.NavigationTypeLinkClicked: return False
                return super().acceptNavigationRequest(url, type, isMainFrame)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
rf = ReadField()
rf.setHtml("<a href=\"http://test\">test</a>")
rf.show()
app.exec()
app.quit()
```

It does not work. I don't get a print statement and instead the link is opened normally, leading to an error page because the server "test" cannot be found. I have two questions.
Why is what I tried not working?
How can I avoid creating the page element outside of the constructor?

Comment: `super().__init__(); self.setPage(Page(self))`.

Answer (score 0):

Despite spending quite some time on this before posting the question, I figured it out shortly after. I guess this shows the benefit of writing down one's questions.

As expected, the answer has to do with "page" being a local variable in the second code.
The solution I found is to store the variable in the class instance being created, like so.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEnginePage

import sys

class ReadField(QWebEngineView) :
        def __init__(self):
                self.page = Page()
                super().__init__(self.page, None)

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
        def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, type, isMainFrame: bool) -> bool:
                print("hello")
                if type == QWebEnginePage.NavigationType.NavigationTypeLinkClicked: return False
                return super().acceptNavigationRequest(url, type, isMainFrame)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
rf = ReadField()
rf.setHtml("<a href=\"http://test\">test</a>")
rf.show()
app.exec()
app.quit()
```

I guess this has to do with the local variable reaching the end of scope and being garbage collectd, but I do not know much about these mechanisms. If anyone would like to clarify this, I would be grateful.

Comment: A possibly more accurate (and Qt affine) approach would be to create the page with the view as its parent (and in this way you don't even need the reference): `super().__init__()` `self.setPage(Page(self))`. Note the inversion of the `super()` call and the page creation, which is necessary because at that point the `__init__` has not been called yet and the view is not a fully constructed QObject. Alternatively, reparent it afterwards: `page = Page()` `super().__init__(page)` `page.setParent(self)`.